# How to combine subsequent list elements into a new list in R?

Tags: r, list, functional-programming

For example: I have a list of matrices, and I would like to evaluate their differences, sort of a 3-D diff. So if I have:

```
m1 <- matrix(1:4, ncol=2)
m2 <- matrix(5:8, ncol=2)
m3 <- matrix(9:12, ncol=2)
mat.list <- list(m1,m2,m3)
```

I want to obtain

```
mat.diff <- list(m2-m1, m3-m2)
```

The solution I found is the following:

```
mat.diff <- mapply(function (A,B) B-A, mat.list[-length(mat.list)], mat.list[-1])
```

Is there a nicer/built-in way to do this?

Comment: It'd be nice to have this explained with a (small) reproducible example.

Comment: I read your mind and edited the question :)

Comment: @piccobello, that's still not reproducible. Without even trying, I guarantee an `X1 not found` type of error.

Comment: OK thanks Arun for your example!

Comment: I merged @Arun's example into the question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with just `lapply` or other ways of looping:

```
mat.diff <- lapply( tail( seq_along(mat.list), -1 ), 
                    function(i) mat.list[[i]] - mat.list[[ i-1 ]] )
```

Comment: My favorite so far, however I'd use a more readable lapply(2:length(mat.list),...), as in @Arun's answer. Anything better?

Comment: using `seq_along` is better because it handles discrepancies like the scenario where `length(mat.list) < 2`. In this case, `2:length(mat.list)` would produce `2:1` where as `seq_along(mat.list)` would produce `1` and wouldn't result in errors/wrong results.

Comment: Also, what do you mean anything better? What are you hoping for??

Comment: magic.function <- function(FUN='-', listarg) { lapply( tail( seq_along(listarg), -1 ), function(i) FUN( listarg[[i]], listarg[[i-1]]))}

Comment: Thanks Greg! I meant to ask if there was a native R function that behaves like magic.function. Thanks to all for your ideas!

Comment: @piccobello, the `Reduce` function comes closest, though it accumulates rather than just looking at pairs.  The `diff` function does what you want for vectors, but does not work on lists.  There are functions in packages that do a "running apply" or "rolling apply" which could do this if they work on lists.  It seems like there should be something more built in to do this, but I don't know of anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `combn` to generate the indexes of matrix and apply a function on each combination.

```
       combn(1:length(l),2,FUN=function(x) 
            if(diff(x) == 1)         ## apply just for consecutive index 
                  l[[x[2]]]-l[[x[1]]], 
                  simplify = FALSE)  ## to get a list
```

Using @Arun data, I get :

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    4
[2,]    4    4

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    4
[2,]    4    4
```